# How to parse Firebase Dynamic Link parameter values and put it in a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm building an app that can receive Firebase's Dynamic Links and redirects it into a certain `UIViewController`. I've followed the steps on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSC5ed6OowA), but there's something that I still don't understand. So after I followed the steps above, I print my link on the debug area to something like this:

> Incoming link parameter is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx.xxx&referrer=utm_source%3DXXX%26utm_medium%3Dxxx%26utm_campaign%3DXXX
>
> Parameter id has a value of com.xxx.xxx
>
> Parameter referrer has a value of utm_source=XXX&utm_medium=xxx&utm_campaign=XXX

This works perfectly, but what I want to do is I want to get the values of `utm_source`, `utm_medium` and `utm_campaign` and store it into a variable. I'm still uncertain on how do I manage to achieve this. Here is my code:

```
func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink) {
        guard let url = dynamicLink.url else {
            print("Dynamic Link has no URL")
            return
        }
        
        print("Incoming link parameter is \(url.absoluteString)")
        guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false), let queryItems = components.queryItems else { return }
        for queryItem in queryItems {
            print("Parameter \(queryItem.name) has a value of \(queryItem.value ?? "")")
        }
    }
```

So how do I manage to do this? Feel free to ask if you need any more information. Thank you.

Comment: What's the difficulty you are facing? Get the values that you want? or passing the value to viewcontroller?

Comment: @Frankenstein getting the values and store it to a variable, sorry if that's redundant. I'll edit the question

Comment: Your url seems to be incorrect. If the value of referrer is empty your should replace the url with this url: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx.xxx&referrer=&utm_source%3DXXX%26utm_medium%3Dxxx%26utm_campaign%3DXXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best answer or the right code design but fortunately I managed to solve by changing `handleIncomingDynamicLink` function to something like this:

```
func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink) {
        guard let url = dynamicLink.url else {
            print("Dynamic Link has no URL")
            return
        }
        
        print("Incoming link parameter is \(url.absoluteString)")
        guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false), let queryItems = components.queryItems else { return }
        for queryItem in queryItems {
            if queryItem.name == "referrer" {
                print("Referrer found")
                
                let referrerString = "https://xxx.page.link/details?\(queryItem.value ?? "")"
                let referrerUrl = URL(string: referrerString)
                
                guard let queryItemComponents = URLComponents(url: referrerUrl!, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false), let itemComponents = queryItemComponents.queryItems else {
                    print("Referrer string couldn't be casted as a URL")
                    return
                }
                
                for item in itemComponents {
                    print("Parameter \(item.name) has a value of \(item.value ?? "")")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically what I did was I take the referrer value of the main URL and make it a "custom URL" so that I could parse the values by using the `URLComponents` function. The output is exactly what I expected to be.

> Incoming link parameter is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx.xxx&referrer=utm_source%3Dxxx%26utm_medium%3Dxxx%26utm_campaign%3Dxxx
>
> Referrer found
>
> Parameter utm_source has a value of xxx
>
> Parameter utm_medium has a value of xxx
>
> Parameter utm_campaign has a value of xxx

Answer (score 0):

Here's is how you can make a struct and assign the values to it.

```swift
struct MyVariable {
    var referrer: String?, utm_source: String?, utm_medium: String?, utm_campaign: String?
}

func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: URL?) {
    guard let string = dynamicLink?.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding,
        let url = URL(string: string) else {
            print("Dynamic Link has no URL")
            return
    }
    var myVariable = MyVariable()
    guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false),
        let queryItems = components.queryItems else { return }
    for queryItem in queryItems {
        if queryItem.name == "referrer" {
            myVariable.referrer = queryItem.value
        } else if queryItem.name == "utm_source" {
            myVariable.utm_source = queryItem.value
        } else if queryItem.name == "utm_medium" {
            myVariable.utm_medium = queryItem.value
        } else if queryItem.name == "utm_campaign" {
            myVariable.utm_campaign = queryItem.value
        }
    }
    print("MyVariable: \(myVariable)")
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work because the value of `utm_source`, `utm_medium` and `utm_campaign` included in `referrer` value. So i can't call `queryItem.value` to get their values. Is there any other way to handle this?